# Offline functionality in asp.net mvc with local storage

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, local-storage, offline-caching

I want to add offline functionality in my existing asp.net mvc 4.7 web application. I searched a lot and found many links to add offline functionality in html pages but could not find any link for asp.net mvc. please provide me link of any sample work done related to this.

Answer (score 1):

The modern web ecosystem is made up of many different types of scenarios of how users interact with online content.We imagined leveraging the browser to bring fully competent web applications to the desktop, but failed due to the lack of decent browser support. Although there were some caching techniques available before, they were never really designed with the intention of making web applications run completely offlin.

So if you want to make a offline suported web appilcain you should know --

1. How to manage, refesh, save manifest files both Server & client side
2. How to manage caching both Server & client side
3. How to swapping cache
4. How to Handling events
5. How to Detect whether the browser is online or offline and let user know.

you can find more information in below articles --

1. [Build an HTML5 Offline Application with Application Cache, Web Storage and ASP.NET MVC](https://www.codemag.com/article/1112051/Build-an-HTML5-Offline-Application-with-Application-Cache-Web-Storage-and-ASP.NET-MVC)
2. [HTML5 offline web applications using ASP.NET MVC](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Offline-Web-Apps/)

Comment: It might be helpful for my current project